# Rack SSL Enforcer for root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

I use [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) gem, and this current configration for specific path :

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => [%r{^/users/*}]
```

And now I want to set https protocol only `root_path` and `^/users/*`, I try with

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => ['/', %r{^/users/*}
```

But all page have https protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The string constraint '/' matches everything *beginning* with '/', so use a Regex instead.

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => [%r{^/users/*}, %r{^/\z}]
```

might do the trick.